# Store re-direct on store deletion

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, redirect

I am new to Magento and I've inherited a Magento built website.

I have been asked to reduce the number of store views we have. Is it possible to put a redirect on a store view and all of it's URL's so its redirecting to a different store view e.g mystore.com/fr/variableproducts would redirect to mystore.com/de/variableproducts
The store view it requires a redirect to is not the default store and I need to do this redirect from several stores to several stores.

Please can anyone point me in the right direction. I have researched and as yet haven't found a suitable answer to what I need.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will be able to do this within Magento very easily.  The easiest way to handle this would be with Apache/Nginx rewrites at the server-level instead of at the Magento application level.

Something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location ~^/fr/(.*)? {
        return 301 http://$server_name/de/$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this infomation it is much appreciated. I also need to redirect users to a none default store. Am I right in assuming that this would need to be done in the same way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by non default store, but yes.  It could be done this way.